# Gmail 'Account Activity' consists of my Android logins?

Tags: google-account, ip-addresses, google-hangouts

Wanted to check if there is a way to see what is the IP address of my own Gmail (Hangout) account of my Android device.

I don't have direct access to the device right now. But my Gmail/Google+/Hangouts etc. are configured and are online. I wanted to trace the device using the IP address which it is using.

I already checked [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/detecting-ip-address-in-google-talk-mail). It asks about the IP address of another person in chat. What am asking is my own IP address.

Comment: If all you want is to find the IP address of your Android, just visit a site like [WhatsMyIp.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) or just type `ip` as a Google Search. More information on Android Stack Exchange: [Find carrier allocated public IP address](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25283) and [How can I see what IP address my android phone has?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2984)

Comment: If that's not what you're asking about, we need more details.

Comment: @AlEverett, Thanks for the response. Please check the updated information. I need the ip from the device which I dont have direct access to. The only access I have is the gmail/hangouts that I can login to same account from the desktop browser.

Comment: The question which I asked is a straight forward one. Whether the 'Account Activity' feature in gmail show the android hangouts ip address or not. I don't understand why it is down voted.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it's off-topic here. If you're trying to track down a missing phone http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-phone might be helpful.

Comment: @AlEverett, Thanks for the information. Already checked with Android Stack Exchange. But I didn't get the answer to my question yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would appear to be **no**.

Gmail last activity shows IP addresses, but only for Gmail activity, and even then not for the Android Gmail app (presumably unless you force it to log in).

Your [Google Account Recent Activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) page doesn't show IP addresses, just locations. And, even so, I only see sign-ins, not any generic Hangout activity.

Do you have Dropbox? Perhaps you can [find the IP address of your phone](http://smartphones.wonderhowto.com/how-to/dropbox-could-help-you-find-your-lost-stolen-smartphone-0141482/) that way.

Answer (score -1):

if you send an email to yourself, but from your mobile phone, (obviously from any domain except Gmail) you can see the ip address of the phone, with the method used to see the IP of the emails received ..

Comment: This isn't much help when the point of finding the IP address is to trace the Android device. Why would the person who has your phone send you an email from your own account?